# How to update the array value in Indexed dB? I don't want to overwrite the whole array but to concatenate a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb

I am using indexed DB to store key-value pairs of the below type.

Key - String (type)
Value - Array (type)

e.g.

### **Indexed Table**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| nums | [1,2,3] |

I need to update the `"nums"` array without **overwriting** the array in indexed DB directly.
I want to push new items `[4,5]` to this `nums` array like using `push` function in JavaScript.

After this push operation, table should look like:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| nums | [1,2,3,4,5] |

Comment: overwrite the whole array or change how you store objects in the database